# Alternative to factory pattern for possibly hundreds of small classes

Tags: design-patterns, go, factory-pattern

I'm working on a small game/simulator, written in GoLang, in which there will be potentially hundreds of abilities.  For each player, they will have between 1 and 3 abilities.  I'll have these stored with either strings or Ids.  What is the best way to instantiate these abilities.  Normally I'd use a factory class, but with as many as I'm talking about, I'm not sure that's the best way.

Comment: using empty struct for each of the abilities could be interesting (an empty struct has a size of zero, an array of empty struct has a size of 0: http://dave.cheney.net/2014/03/25/the-empty-struct, and http://stackoverflow.com/a/22627240/6309)

Comment: There are no classes in Go, and without understanding what you're trying to do (beyond create hundreds of something-or-others, which is a means to an end, rather than an end) it's impossible to answer the question about what pattern is most appropriate.

Comment: @Anonymous: kinda rude. Help them ask the right question rather than belittle the one they asked.
A better summary would be: "How to scale or replace the factory pattern for hundreds of simple types?"

Comment: @JaysonBailey: I'm confused by the sentence "I'll have these stored with either strings or Ids" stored where? why aren't they stored as interfaces? Can you clarify?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can still use the factory pattern, it's what the [encoding/gob](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/gob/) package uses.

playground: http://play.golang.org/p/LjR4PTTCvw

For example in `abilities.go` you could have

```
type Ability interface {
    Execute()
}

var abilities = struct {
    m map[string]AbilityCtor
    sync.RWMutex
}{m: make(map[string]AbilityCtor)}

type AbilityCtor func() Ability

func Register(id string, newfunc AbilityCtor) {
    abilities.Lock()
    abilities.m[id] = newfunc
    abilities.Unlock()
}

func GetAbility(id string) (a Ability) {
    abilities.RLock()
    ctor, ok := abilities.m[id]
    abilities.RUnlock()
    if ok {
        a = ctor()
    }
    return
}
```

Then for each ability (in separate files probably) you could do something like :

```
type Fireball struct{}

func (s *Fireball) Execute() {
    fmt.Println("FIREBALL EXECUTED")
}

func init() {
    Register("Fireball", func() Ability {
        return &Fireball{}
    })
}

func main() {
    if fireball := GetAbility("Fireball"); fireball != nil { //could be nil if not found
        fireball.Execute()
    }
}
```

Comment: This can be simplified. `init()` functions are always non-concurrent. So it's safe to manipulate the `abilities` var directly without a mutex. `Register()` could still be called from concurrent goroutines after initialization, but I think in this case it's a non-issue as `Register()` is designed to be called during `init()`.

Comment: `ctor()` is user supplied code, it should be panic safe. Use `defer abilities.Unlock()`.

Comment: Good point about the mutex, however `defer` adds overhead that's really not needed unless you have multiple exit points.

Comment: What I meant was that `ctor()` is not your code and in theory it could panic. Go does a good job of keeping panic to a minimal nuisance. It is safe to assume a function won't panic unless it specifically says it will (very rare, possibly bad style), or the code originates from the user. In those cases defer is a necessary evil.

Comment: Switched to defer, I misunderstood your first comment :)

Comment: Hmm, I think I'm getting close on this.  However, when I try to call Get(GetAbility in my case), it's just hanging.  http://play.golang.org/p/jke7lGLeHP

Comment: It was my mistake, that was supposed to be `defer abilities.RUnlock()` not `defer abilities.Unlock()`, I fixed the answer and posted a link.

Comment: Thanks @OneOfOne, that's perfect.  I'm still reading through and trying to understand how it all works as I'm just learning golang from ruby.