# go channel take empty struct as input. Can this input be anything?

Tags: go

a := make(chan struct{})

Such this, go channel take empty struct as input. Can this input be anything?

thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No: it can be an empty struct (`struct{}{}`), not "anything"

To be "anything", you would need `interface{}`.

As I explain in "[Go Golang : anonymous struct and empty struct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22627240/6309)", an empty struct is useful to pass an object of size... 0! It is a good way to signal the completion that something has happened.

Answer (score 0):

`struct{}` is much like the unit type in other languages; it only has one value with no information. The values you get from such a channel would contain no information, but such a channel could be used for signalling when some event happened. A goroutine receiving from that channel would wake up whenever something is sent to it.